# defining platform independent application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

A standalone application developed using Java can be called a platform independent application.

In the same way, can I call an application which runs on a browser and is developed using Java EE a platform independent application?

Comment: So you want to define standalone application or platform independent application? title and body are contradictory

Comment: Yes, you can. Nobody is stopping you.

Comment: Irrespective of it's a web application or standalone application, it is a platform independent as long as target OS has a JVM implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java EE doesn't run "on a browser". You would typically use Javascript and HTML over HTTP to connect to a Java EE backend. Your **Java** code will be running on a server somewhere - not running in each browser.

So, if you're talking about HTML and Javascript, then the answer is... tricky.

Javascript is an interpreted language: it runs through an engine. So, technically **is** platform-independent.